# What is Ruby equivalent of Python's `s= "hello, %s. Where is %s?" % ("John","Mary")`

Tags: python, ruby, string-formatting

In Python, this idiom for string formatting is quite common

```
s = "hello, %s. Where is %s?" % ("John","Mary")
```

What is the equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: There's no string concatenation, only string formatting. And google will answer this faster than even SO ever could... it took me about 20 seconds to find out you can do exactly the same in Ruby.

Comment: You're not asking for concatenation, your asking for formatting/substitution. You should change your question. By the way, in ruby, concatenation is performed with + or << operators.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

The easiest way is [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html).  You can inject little pieces of Ruby code directly into your strings.

```
name1 = "John"
name2 = "Mary"
"hello, #{name1}.  Where is #{name2}?"
```

You can also do format strings in Ruby.

```
"hello, %s.  Where is %s?" % ["John", "Mary"]
```

Remember to use square brackets there.  Ruby doesn't have tuples, just arrays, and those use square brackets.

Comment: I would definitively use the first one, it looks more readable to me

Comment: The first one won't work, the #{} looks for a variable, so in this case it'd be printing the John variable, not the string "John".

The second one looks correct.

Comment: You should also be careful to **always use double quotes** as `'#{name1}'` is not the same as `"#{name1}"`.

Comment: @Droogans: Thanks for the tip. Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: String interpolation does not work in single quotes, you must use double quotes. For example:`'#{"abc"}' # => "\#{\"abc\"}"`, but what you want is `"#{"abc"}" # => "abc"`

Comment: The format string method also allows you to tweak the format (appropriately enough): `"%2d: %05d" % [9, 130] => " 9: 00130"`

Comment: The first way is not an equivalent - the template can't be passed around as a value.

Comment: Doing something like `"%-20s %s" % ["John", "Mary"]` is a great reason to know about the second one! Thank you :)

Answer (score 55):

In Ruby > 1.9 you can do this:

```
s =  'hello, %{name1}. Where is %{name2}?' % { name1: 'John', name2: 'Mary' }
```

[See the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-25)

Comment: I edited in the *Idomatic Ruby* equivalent there - but now I notice the accepted answer already does that - removed the 'edit' again :-/

Comment: When using a hash with the string % operator, if the key symbol referenced in the format string isn't present, you'll get a KeyError.

Answer (score 22):

Almost the same way:

```
"hello, %s. Where is %s?" % ["John","Mary"]
# => "hello, John. Where is Mary?"
```

Comment: In Ruby, do the square brackets mean a tuple? I thought square brackets are lists...

Comment: @TIMEX: This question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525957/tuples-in-ruby

Comment: Ruby doesn't have tuples (at least not forged into the language). Yeah, it's an array ("list" in Python should really be called arrays...).

Answer (score 10):

Actually almost the same

```
s = "hello, %s. Where is %s?" % ["John","Mary"]
```