# String formatting in a python dictionary like Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, language-comparisons

In Ruby, you can do something like:

```
a = 4
b = 5
match = {}
match["#{a}-#{b}"] = 0
```

Then, if i say:

```
match["4-5"]
```

The result is 0.

Can I do something similar in a python dictionary? I can't seem to get string formatting to work with a dictionary.

EDIT:

With f-strings in Python 3+, one can now do something like:

```
match[f"{a}-{b}"] = 0
```

Comment: I think the closest you can get is by using the format operator: `match["%d-%d" % (4, 5)] = 0`.

Comment: That's the Python equivalent I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

- How to do ruby-style string variable placeholders in python.

### Solution

- Python has numerous options for doing string variable interpolation
- Among them, a couple prominent approaches:

  - `str.format` in python version 2.6 and above
  - [f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/f-string/info) in python version 3.6 and above

### Example

```
  import pprint
  ## using python str.format
  match     = {}
  a = 4
  b = 5
  match["{a}-{b}".format(a=a,b=b)] = 0
  pprint.pprint(match)
  pass

  ## result
  {'4-5': 0}
```

### See also

- [Python string variable placeholder interpolation extended discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)
- [Python has **a lot** of options for string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-depre)