# Is there any way to access variable like $var (similar to shell scripting) in python?

Tags: python, shell, variables, copy, language-comparisons

Hi I'm new to python programming.

I want to copy a file from source to destination. I'm using shutil.copy2(src,dst).
But in src and dst path , I want to use variable.

For example (variable name): pkg_name = XYZ_1000
so src path will be : /home/data/**$pkg_name**/file.zip

In shell we can use $pkg_name to access variable, so is there any similar way in python?

Main concern is , if I want to use a variable(s) in copy command , how can I achieve that in python ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/string-interpolation-in-python

Comment: Thanks. But my question is different. Let me know how can I use a variable within copy command in python ?

Comment: Looks like it was the same, given the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pkg_name = XYZ_1000
```

using format()

```
src_path = "/home/data/{pkg_name}/file.zip".format(pkg_name=pkg_name)
```

OR

```
src_path = "/home/data/%s/file.zip" % pkg_name
```

OR

```
src_path = "/home/data/" + pkg_name + "/file.zip"
```

OR

```
src_path = string.Template("/home/data/$pkg_name/file.zip").substitute(locals())
# Or maybe globals() instead of locals(), depending on where pkg_name is defined.
```

Comment: I added an example of a `string.Template` just for completeness. I wouldn't actually recommend using it, and there are a few ways of passing the value of `pkg_name` if you want to [read about it in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings).