# python , changing dictionary values with iteration

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
max_id = 10
    for i in range(max_id):
        payload = "{\"text\": 'R'+str(i),\"count\":\"1 \",}"
        print(payload)
```

I want to iterate through this , and have the value of text be set to "R1", "R2" ... Upon debugging the output is:

```
{"text": 'R'+str(i),"count":"1",}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double-check your double quotes. The syntax highlighting in your question might give you a hint.

Comment: [String interpolation in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/string-interpolation-in-python)

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/string-interpolation-in-python, I've come up with payload = "{\"text\": %s,\"count\":\"1 \"}" % ("R"+str(i))  -Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(max_id):
    payload = "{\"text\": R"+str(i)+",\"count\":\"1 \",}"
    print(payload)
```

Problem with your double quotes.

Output:

```
{"text": R0,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R1,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R2,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R3,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R4,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R5,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R6,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R7,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R8,"count":"+i+ ",}
{"text": R9,"count":"+i+ ",}
```

My be you are looking for this one.

```
for i in range(10):
    payload = "{\"text\": R%s,\"count\":\"1 \",}" %(i)
    print(payload)
```

Comment: Thanks , I think people wanted the more pythonic method, please see my comment. Your way does work though

Comment: @user61629 Updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: It's easier to read and write if you use single quotes as delimiters: `payload = '{"text": R%s,"count":"1 ",}" %(i)`

Comment: I'm working with windows so escaping helps

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that helps