# Formatting multiple %s with a single variable

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a string with unknown number of `%s` that need to be formatted with a single string.

For instance, if I had the string `"%s some %s words %s"` and wanted to format it with the word `house` it should output `"house some house words house"`

Doing the following gives me an error:

```
>>> "%s some %s words %s" % ("house")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

So, I decided to do the following, which works but seem to be overly complex for such a simple problem.

```
var = "house"
tup = (var,)
while True:
    try:
        print "%s some %s words %s" % tup
        break
    except:
        tup += (var,)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: That's a creative solution, actually!

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a short example of subclassing `string.Template`, another option to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know for sure you're subbing `%s` you can do it like this:

```
var = "house"
tup = (var,)
txt = "%s some %s words %s"

print txt % (tup * txt.count("%s"))
```

But a better solution is to use `str.format()` which uses a different syntax, but lets you specify items by number, so you can reuse them:

```
var = "house"
txt = "{0} some {0} words {0}"

print txt.format(var)
```

Comment: For the `%s` version, you might want to do something like `txt % (tup * re.findall(r'%%|%s', txt).count('%s'))` to avoid counting instances of `%s` where the `%` is escaped.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to really support using `%` it gets complicated pretty quickly.  :-)

Comment: It is not generic as it assumes length of tuple to be 1. Check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40518447/2063361) to handle it for varying length tuples

Comment: Using a variable length tuple wouldn't make much sense since the question is about how to get *one* string interpolated in multiple places in a string.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few options:

### Format string (and Formatter class)

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) is the most pythonic way and pretty simple to read.  Either style is popular:

#### Position arguments

```
'{0} some {0} words {0}'.format('house')
```

#### Named arguments

```
'{word} some {word} words {word}'.format(word='house')
```

In a comment you mentioned preserving the original format string because of other legacy code.  You could hack around that like so:

```
'%s some %s words %s'.replace('%s', '{0}').format('house')
```

(I don't recommend it but you could "short circuit" this idea line by using `'house'` in the replace call instead of `'{0}'`.)

That said, I really think changing the template string in the first place is a better idea.

### Template strings

One more alternative comes to mind after glancing at the `string` docs: the older [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#template-strings) class.  By default it substitutes `$`-based values, but you can subclass it overriding the delimiter character.   For example:

```
class MyTemplate(Template):
    """
    Overriding default to maintain compatibility with legacy code.
    """
    delimiter = '%'


t = MyTemplate('%s some %s words %s')
t.substitute(s='house')
```

Remember this is less common but you could write it once and re-use it every time you work with a string like this (assuming there's only one input value being substituted in).  Writing it once is Pythonic at least!

### Literal string interpolation

In Python 3.6, [Ruby-style string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/string-interpolation-in-python) is another option that the community hasn't come to a consensus on yet.  For example:

```
s = 'house'
f'{s} some {s} words {s}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `format`?

```
"{0} some {0} words {0}".format("house")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the format of the string since it must be backwards compatible with the current system (I get it from a configuration file). Good solution though.