# How to send the value of a Python variable to JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine

I am using the Google App Engine to display a Google map on a web page.

I want to bring the latitude and longitude in the database and display it on the map. To do this, I need to pass the imported latitude and longitude to JavaScript in HTML. I have tried several ways but it is useless. (ex. `{{variable}}` is useless.)

How best to debug or otherwise proceed on this?

```
class Map(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    db = connect_to_cloudsql()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select latitude,longitude from User;""")

    data=cursor.fetchone() 
    lat=data[0]
    lng=data[1]

    formstring = """
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="ko-KR">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="9EqLgIzCmwFo7XAcSe4sBNZ_t0gULadyeF9BCO0DY3k"/>
    </head>
    <body class>
    <style>
     #map {
        width: 80%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
    <div style="position:relative;width:1080px;margin:0 auto;z-index:11">
    <div class="container" role="main">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <br><br>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <script>
      function initMap() {

        var uluru = {lat: {lat} , lng: {lng} };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
        """
```

Comment: your way of forming html code is bad, but if it is so - break the html code string append the lat-lng values to the string and form the html code.

Comment: Don't write HTML in your Python file. GAE supports Jinja2, you should use it.

Comment: If you still insist on forming your string this way, make sure you replace all `{` with `{{` and `}` with `}}` except for the `{lat}` and {`lng`}, then just call `.format(lat=lat, lng=lng}` on the `formstring`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

Comment: """{{lat:{0} lng:{1}}}""".format(lat, lng)

Comment: @Carlos should be more descriptive: if you're not using some sort of templating engine, you probably want a triple '{' `>>> "foo{{{bar}}}".format(bar="baz")` becomes `'foo{baz}'` as pairs will be replaced with a literal '{' when using `.format`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [string formatters](https://pyformat.info/). As you grow your web app, you'll probably want to switch to using templates because they are more robust. [Webapp2 provides support](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html) for [Jinja2 templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), which are widely used and will make your life easier in the long run.

But in the short run, use string formatters:

```
formstring = """
<!DOCTYPE html> 
...

    var uluru = {lat: %f , lng: %f };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
...
""" % (lat, lng)  # assuming lat/lng are floats, use %s instead of %f for strings
```

Alternatively, use the "new way":

```
formstring = """<html.......{lat: {:f}, lng: {:f}...""".format(lat, lng)
```

Again, look at [string formatters](https://pyformat.info/).