# Python shorthand for .format

Tags: python

Ahead Warning! A Python newbie and quite a spoiled question ahead!

Is there a way to shorthand:

```
"{} blabla ... {}".format(x, y)
```

Into something like:

```
"{} blabla ... {}" % (x, y)
```

Using operator overloading like syntax or otherwise?

**Not talking about old style string formatting which took typed %s ...**

Comment: There is old-style formatting, which uses the `%` operator, but it is much less feature rich than using the `.format` method. There is also new (Python 3.6) f-strings.

Comment: updating question...

Comment: Read this: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: This answer lists the most common options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4450610/2878796

Comment: @UnholySheep you got it right!

Comment: Why would you want to? You're saving 6 characters (4, if you don't skip the whitespace), and your code would easily be mistaken for an incorrect use of the real `%` string operator.

Comment: chepner - The other direction is usually the problem. You put %d and got a string...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this in Python 3.6 or above:

```
f"{x} blabla ... {y}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. But strongly advice to not do this.

```
fmt = str.format
print fmt("{} blabla ... {}", x, y)
```

`fmt` here is just an example.

If ever you're planning to do this, you can give whatever name you like but make sure you don't override any existing variable/function names.

Comment: This is worse than you may think. `_` is the conventional name of the function used by the `gettext` module to localize strings.

Comment: Yeah. I was going to edit it.

Comment: (Or, I guess, people conventionally define `_` to mean `gettext.gettext`, so there is no automatic conflict.)