# Executing Curl command in Python

Tags: python, curl

I have values in two variables

```
SessionId=Pxsvdsdruhn 
ServerUrl=https://app3.xxxxxxxxcloud.com/saas
```

I want to pass these values in curl command and execute it from python script. I tried below but its giving syntax error

```
os.system("curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "icSessionId":"SessionId" ServerUrl/api/v2/agent")
```

Any pointers where i am wrong?

Comment: You're trying to put quotes in a string delimited with the same quotes? Also, why don't you use a Python-level client, e.g. `requests`, instead of shelling out to curl?

Comment: combine single and double quotes so that you can keep double quotes in the command

Comment: `requests` is the bees knees, use that

Answer (score -1):

The way to do what you are looking for is a technique called string interpolation. Fortunately, this has already been answered on StackOverflow.

[Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

I'd also strongly recommend using single quotes around your command so that way you can escape the double quotes in your string. The python interpreter thinks you're putting separate strings together, instead of treating the quotes as an "embedded" string.