# Python variable scoping of two functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

I tried to search the question for a bit but can't find a actual answer. 
I'm trying to implement a function (magic_debug) so that when called in another function (somefunc), it can access the variable
within the somefunc and print it out as follow:

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):
    s2 = s.format(x=x,y=y,z=args[0])
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
    x = 123
    y = ['a', 'b']
    magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y))

somefunc()
```

the expected output --> The value of x is 123, and the list is ['a', 'b'] of len 2

Comment: Why don't you make you (somefunc) method return the value you want? If you need more that one value returned create a class or use a list.

Comment: Hi @PaulDavid ! This is actually an interview question I had earlier. So it need to be implemented via this way.  Can you give me a hint on using class or list to solve this?

Comment: @LeonChen - Are you sure the question was posed exactly as above? If so, what modifications are allowed?

Comment: Hi @zwer I think any modification on magic_debug is okay. I think somefunc is fixed and shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @LeonChen - In that case, check Sraw's answer. Also, if I may offer a piece of unsolicited advice - run away from companies who ask such questions on an interview.

Comment: See my answer below... Minimal code change and formatting

Comment: @zwer Haha! thanks for the advice. Is it because this is too trivial? Probably didn't get the offer anyway :(

Comment: The question is worded strangely. if you want to "access the variable" you'd add "return yourVariable" at the bottom of the magic_debug() method. If you're just looking to get the desired output, most of the answers below will do the trick

Comment: @LeonChen - It's not trivial, it's a _gotcha_ question where an interviewer (or whoever designed the interview questions) tries to pry out of you a piece of potentially obscure knowledge that you most likely won't ever need while working for them and, even if you do, its a few Google searches away. No company worth working for tries to work against their employees, present or future ones, by holding a language and standard library reference over their heads, but I digress...

Comment: @zwer I see your point. Yeah, this one got me pretty bad. Multiple try without success. But I'm glad to have all the constructive support on this one. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a common question, try to use `inspect`.

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):
    import inspect
    parent_local_scope = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    s2 = s.format(**parent_local_scope, z=args[0])
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
    x = 123
    y = ['a', 'b']
    magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y))

somefunc()
```

output:

```
The value of x is 123, and the list is ['a', 'b'] of len 2
```

Comment: If `magic_debug()` can be changed `inspect` is quite a bit of an overkill - it's sufficient to pass `locals()` as expanded `kwargs` (`magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y), **locals())`) and then just re-expand it as: `s.format(z=args[0], **kwargs)` in the `magic_debug()`.

Comment: Sure, you are right. But as I understand, the semantic meaning of this `magic_debug` is that I can access the parent's variables directly, and I want to accept some other parameters. That's difficult to say if it is a good idea and I just give what OP asked.

Comment: Thank you Sraw and zwer , it the task, I believe any modification to the magic_debug is acceptable. So I think Sraw's solution can solve this problem. zwer, can you elaborate more on your thought? I'm very interested in yours too!

Comment: @LeonChen - Ok, I've added the 'other' approach. It does require the change of the call to `magic_debug()` tho.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it?

```
def magic_debug(s, vars_dict):

    s2 = s.format(**vars_dict)
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
   x = 123         # variables are indent in python
   y = ['a', 'b']  # so they're in the function scope

                   # and so is this function that somefunc calls - 
   vars_dict = vars()
   vars_dict['z'] = len(y)
   magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', vars_dict)

somefunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

If any modification is allowed as long as you keep the spirit of the question, you can use `locals()` to pass the local scope to the `magic_debug` function, i.e.:

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):
    s2 = s.format(z=args[0], **kwargs)
    print(s2)

def somefunc():
    x = 123
    y = ['a', 'b']
    magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y), **locals())

somefunc()
# The value of x is 123, and the list is ['a', 'b'] of len 2
```

And if you're allowed to change the function signatures you can pass the `locals()` without expansion, too. But if you cannot change the function being debugged, then peeking into the previous frame is the only way. [@Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588279/sraw) already covered that [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641717/7553525).

Comment: Much appreciated! @zwer , I believe the function being debugged can't be changed. Learn a lot in this hour from all the awesome responses :)

Answer (score 0):

try this - you need to indent your function

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):

    s2 = s.format(x=x,y=y,z=args[0])
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
   x = 123         # variables are indent in python
   y = ['a', 'b']  # so they're in the function scope

                   # and so is this function that somefunc calls - 
   magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y))

somefunc()
```

Comment: thanks for the indentation, @Steven but I don't think magic_debug can access the x,y even with the indentation.

Comment: also `'The value of x is {0}, and the list is {1} of len {2}'.format(x,y,len(y))` should work

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Change some of your code around to look like this:

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):
    s2 = s.format(x=args[1],y=kwargs.pop('y', ''),z=args[0])
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
    x = 123
    y = ['a', 'b']
    magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', len(y), x, y=y)

somefunc()
```

Your output will be perfect. You're adding the **Kargs but you don't use it. The above code uses the **Karg to store the array.

Output:

```
The value of x is 123, and the list is ['a', 'b'] of len 2
```

Edit for fewer arguments:

```
def magic_debug(s, *args, **kwargs):
    s2 = s.format(x=args[1],y=args[0],z=len(args[0]))
    print(s2)


def somefunc():
    x = 123
    y = ['a', 'b']
    magic_debug('The value of x is {x}, and the list is {y} of len {z}', y, x)

somefunc()
```