# Trying to display any number that is entered into a url, using Django 1.1

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm currently learning regex patterns, using DJango 1.1. More specifically, I am trying to display whatever **number** is entered into the url using the '\d+' pattern. I'm brand new to DJango, so I hope that description wasn't too vague. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My **urls.py** url pattern is:

```py
url(r'^(?P<number>\d+)$', views.show)
```

My **views.py** method is:

```py
def show(request, number):
    return HttpResponse("placeholder to display blog number: {number}")
```

I don't quite understand what i'm missing.

If I enter the number 20 into my url: localhost:0000/**20**, I'm expecting to see an output of:

```py
placeholder to display number: 20
```

But instead, I get an output of:

```py
placeholder to display number: {number}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `HttpResponse` to:

```
return HttpResponse(f"placeholder to display blog number: {number}")
```

More information can be found on [**`documentation`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) regarding formatted string literals.

FYI: this solution will work for [**`python 3.6+`**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals), for other python versions you can format the string in following way:

```
return HttpResponse(
    "placeholder to display blog number: {number}".format(number=number)
)
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! Thank you for the help. I will definitely review the documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to format the response. It should be like,

`return HttpResponse(f"placeholder to display blog number: {number}")`

In python `f"strings"` are used for integrating a value into a string

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and thank you for describing why this works for my specific issue.