# Snowflake Python connector insert doesn't accept variables

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Using snowflake connector I am trying to insert a record in a table.

In snowflake [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#creating-tables-and-inserting-data) they have shown examples with hard coded strings, but when I try to use my variables instead, it doesn't work. Please suggest how to use variables in this case.

```
conn.cursor().execute(
            "INSERT INTO cm.crawling_metrics(FEED_DATE,COMP_NAME,REFRESH_TYPE,CRAWL_INPUT,CRAWL_SUCCESS) VALUES " +
            "(score_creation_date,compName,sRefreshType,mp_sku_count,comp_sku_count)"
```

I get the below error

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 100
>   invalid identifier 'SCORE_CREATION_DATE'

**NOTE**: In the above code if i hard code with String instead of variables, it works.

Kindly suggest what is the right way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation / formatting for your code to use these as actual variables:

```
conn.cursor().execute(
    "INSERT INTO cm.crawling_metrics (FEED_DATE, COMP_NAME, REFRESH_TYPE, CRAWL_INPUT, CRAWL_SUCCESS) VALUES " +
    f"('{score_creation_date}', '{compName}', '{sRefreshType}', '{mp_sku_count}', '{comp_sku_count}')"
)
```

Comment: Can you explain why the character f in the above ? Is it typo ?

Comment: I tried the following but didn't work

conn.cursor().execute(
                "INSERT INTO cm.crawling_metrics(FEED_DATE,COMP_NAME,REFRESH_TYPE,CRAWL_INPUT,CRAWL_SUCCESS) VALUES " +
                "({score_creation_date},{compName},{sRefreshType},{mp_sku_count},{comp_sku_count})"
            )

Got below error syntax error line 1 at position 101 unexpected 'score_creation_date'.
syntax error line 1 at position 123 unexpected 'compName'.
syntax error line 1 at position 134 unexpected 'sRefreshType'.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran `f` is for Python's [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation). Try assigning the string to a variable before passing it to `execute` to see the full generated query. Which Python version are you running?

Comment: It was failing because of data type mismatch during db insert. Added single quotes surrounding the {variable} for appropriate datatype conversion. Updated the answer too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You made my day.