# Pass a variable in a query using snowflake connector and pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parameterise a snowflake query in python but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
 ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, account=xxx)
    cs = ctx.cursor()
    cs.execute("use role {};".format(SNOWFLAKE_ROLE))
    cs.execute("use warehouse {}; ".format(SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE))
    cs.execute("use database {};".format(database))
    cs.execute("use schema {};".format(schema))
    cs.execute("alter warehouse {} resume if suspended;".format(SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE))
    
    id=500000
    
    query="""
    create or replace temp table test  as 
    select *
    from tablename as a
    where acct_id =%id;
    """
    
    df1 = pandas.read_sql_query(query, ctx,params={id})
    print(df1)
```

The error I get is " : must be real number, not str".
I am not sure why I get this error.Is there a better way of passing variables in a query?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works:

```
query="""
    create or replace temp table test  as 
    select *
    from tablename as a
    where acct_id ={id};
    """
df1 = pandas.read_sql_query(query, ctx,params={'acct_id':id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the f-string is easiest I think.
Advantage is that this solution is database independent.

```py
your_param = "Sander"

your_query = f"""
    select *
    from your_table
    where id = '{your_param}'  # if your id is numeric then don't use the single quotes!
"""

df = pd.read_sql(your_query, db_connection)
```

See also: [Snowflake Python connector insert doesn't accept variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985516/snowflake-python-connector-insert-doesnt-accept-variables)

Comment: The disadvantage is that this is insecure because it allows for SQL injection

Comment: @PeterOlson:  agree, it depends on the usecase