# Add a variable to a link to make an Api call Python

Tags: python, http, hyperlink, string-formatting

I want to put the id in the link because I want to make an api call

```
id= 156
url1 = 'https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?r='<id>'&px=HS&ps=2020&p=0&rg=1&cc=total'

response1 = requests.get(url1)


print(response1.url)
```

Comment: You can use an f-string `f"...{id}..."`

Comment: You can use the f"string method if its python 3
and you can use format method on a string for both versions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options here, if you want to add a lot of variables to the url or want your code to look clean, I suggest using an f-string as shown below:

```py
url1 = f'https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?r={id}&px=HS&ps=2020&p=0&rg=1&cc=total'
```

This way you can put any variable in your string with just saying {variable}.

Don't forget to put the f before the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 I would suggest the f"string" method as people wrote above me.

I personally like the format as it works for both 3 and 2

```
url1 = 'https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?r={0}&px=HS&ps=2020&p=0&rg=1&cc=total'.format(id)
```