# Putting a variable into a string (quote) python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing a problem while calling the variable values within the double quote

Here's my code:

```
AccountID = ["1234567","5678912"]
for account in range(len(AccountID)):
    response = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=(f"arn:aws:iam::{AccountID[account]}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins"), RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session")
    print(response)
```

I have return response output with no variable values

```
File "test3.py", line 19
    response = (RoleArn=(f"arn:aws:iam::{AccountID[account]}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins"), RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session")
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how would i return an expected results like:

```
arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins
arn:aws:iam::5678912:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins
```

Comment: Do you get what you want if you write `f'arn:aws:iam::{AccountID[account]}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins'`? (note the "f" and the braces)

Comment: Adding onto what @ThePhoton said, you probably need to not loop over `range` as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

Comment: You've changed the example quite a bit, invalidating current answers. Now I have to 
 delete mine. And the line in the error traceback doesn't match the line in the script. The script doesn't have a syntax error. You seem to be running multiple versions of the code. Run the script posted and the traceback error will go away (or maybe change to the next error).

Answer (score 0):

You could use f-strings, a very convenient way to refer to variables inside print statements in python.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
response = f"arn:aws:iam::{int(AccountID[0])}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> response = (RoleArn=(f"arn:aws:iam::{AccountID[account]}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins"), RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session")
> ```

The problem here has nothing to do with generating the string.

The problem is that in Python the `=` (assignment) operator does not produce an output value.

So the expression `RoleArn = ...a_bunch_of_stuff...` only assigns that stuff to `RoleArn`. It doesn't produce any output value that can be assigned to `response`.

And the assignement `RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session"` doesn't produce any return value that can be assigned to be part of the tuple that is being assigned to `RoleArn`.

So just break the code up into three lines:

```
RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session"
RoleArn= f"arn:aws:iam::{AccountID[account]}:role/Cloudbees_Jenkins"
response = (RoleArn, RoleSessionName)
```

In recent Python versions (3.8 and newer) you can use the "walrus operator" `:=` to both assign a value and return that value to be used in an expression, but in your code you should not because it IMO makes the code less clear.

Comment: OP seems to have messed up a run of the code. The posted scripted doesn't have this mangled line.

Comment: @tdelaney, Both of the code blocks posted by OP try to use `=` on the r.h.s. of another `=` statement.

Comment: The = on the rhs is part of a keyword parameter assignment and is fine. You could run that code and you would not get a syntax error. When I ran it I got "NameError: name 'sts' is not defined. Did you mean: 'str'?"

Answer (score 0):

```py
AccountID = [1234567,5678912]
for i in AccountID:
    print("arn:aws:iam::",i,"role/Cloudbees_Jenkins")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.