# Escaping a variable (containing an array)

Tags: ruby, arrays, escaping

I want to have a hash `my_statement` as below:

```
my_statement = %|{:foo=>\#{bar_array}}|
```

where `:foo` is the key and the value is to be substituted with the value of `bar_array` later. After I later define `bar_array = ["a","b"]`, I do an `eval` on this statement, and want it to show the following:

```
eval(my_statement)
# => {:foo=>["a", "b"]}
```

I need to escape the variable `bar_array` so that it evaluates not when `my_statement` is assigned but rather when `eval` is called on it. I can't seem to get the escaping of the variable.  I tried `\#`, `#`, `\\#`.

The background of why I am doing this:
I have several statically defined charts backed by SOLR queries.  I took the approach to define these queries in a serializable column in the database (again they "never" change).  There are actually two levels of queries; the first level which gets "all" data for that query; and the second level which is based on the user selecting some data (off of a chart) from the first query - i.e., I need a variable to be part of the second query.  Sometimes (like in this example) the variable will contain an array.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose? Unless you can show a reason for specifically requiring an `eval` there's no way this could be the recommended approach.

Comment: good point - updated my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try string formatting instead. It is not evaluated on creation but rather later.

```
statement = %|{:foo => %s}|
array = ["a", "b"]
eval(statement % array.inspect) #=> {:foo => ["a", "b"]}
array = [1,2,3]
eval(statement % array.inspect) #=> {:foo => [1, 2, 3]}
```

Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554344/what-is-the-ruby-equivalent-of-this-string-formatting) that deals with the above concept

I get highly nervous when I see `eval` so I would recommend finding some other way of accomplishing this! However, this should work if you deem there to be no other means.

Comment: I like this too and will probably use unless I can get out of using eval.

Comment: I agree that eval is not the best but 1) can't seem to find a better solution for my particular case; 2) I'm in demo version right now - so will revisit later.

Answer (score 2):

There are more straightforward ways to do that.

(1) Make it a method

```
def statement; {foo: @array} end
...
# later in the code
@array = %w[a b]
statement # => {:foo => ["a", "b"]}
```

(2) Use a proc

```
statement = ->{{foo: @array}}
...
# later in the code
@array = %w[a b]
statement.call # => {:foo => ["a", "b"]}
```

Comment: Much better than all that mucking around with `eval`! =)

Comment: I like this, but (again sorry I didn't add some background initially) I don't think I can set up the instance var as part of my serialized query.  I believe it will look for the value on load initially.