# Does Ruby have a `Pair` data type?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I need to deal with key / value data.

I dislike using Arrays, because they are not constrained in size (it's too easy to accidentally add more than 2 items, plus you end up needing to validate size later on). Furthermore, indexes of `0` and `1` become magic numbers and do a poor job of conveying meaning ("When I say 0, I really mean `head`...").

Hashes are also not appropriate, as it is possible to accidentally add an extra entry.

I wrote the following class to solve the problem:

```
class Pair
  attr_accessor :head, :tail

  def initialize(h, t)
      @head, @tail = h, t
  end
end
```

It works great and solves the problem, but I am curious to know: does the Ruby standard library comes with such a class already?

Comment: Looks like a linked list to me. Is that the meaning you're trying to convey?

Comment: @flyooi - No, although you could probably do that with my implementation if you wanted to.

Comment: `Pair = Struct.new(:head, :tail)` is a shorter way to write this class.

Comment: *Ruby* **3.2** now has a `Data` class to create pairs/tuples with named fields.  Details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 3.2 has a Data class that lets your create pairs/tuples with named fields.

```
Measure = Data.define(:amount, :unit)
distance = Measure.new(100, 'km') #or Measure.new(amount:100, unit:'km')

distance.amount #=> 100
distance.unit #=> "km"
```

Check out the docs. It's more flexible than this example:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Data.html

Answer (score 4):

No, Ruby doesn't have a standard `Pair` class.

You could take a look at "[Using Tuples in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525957/using-tuples-in-ruby)".

The solutions involve either using a similar class as yours, the [Tuples](https://github.com/KamilLelonek/ruby-tuples) gem or [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Python has [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), but even Java doesn't have one: "[A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)".

Answer (score 3):

You can also use OpenStruct datatype. Probably not exactly what you wanted, but here is an implementation ...

```
require 'ostruct'

foo = OpenStruct.new
foo.head = "cabeza"
foo.tail = "cola"
```

Finally,

```
puts foo.head
 => "cabeza"

puts foo.tail
 => "cola"
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such class in the Ruby core library or standard libraries. It would be nice to have core library support (as well as literal syntax) for tuples, though.

I once experimented with a class very similar to yours, in order to replace the array that gets `yielded` by `Hash#each` with a pair. I found that monkey-patching `Hash#each` to return a pair instead of an array actually breaks surprisingly little code, provided that the pair class responds appropriately to `to_a` and `to_ary`:

```
class Pair
  attr_reader :first, :second

  def to_ary; [first, second] end
  alias_method :to_a, :to_ary

  private

  attr_writer :first, :second

  def initialize(first, second)
    self.first, self.second = first, second
  end

  class << self; alias_method :[], :new end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special type, you can use a 2-element array with a little helper to give the pairs a consistent order.  E.g.:

```
def pair(a, b)
  (a.hash < b.hash) ? [a, b] : [b, a]
end

distances = {
  pair("Los Angeles", "New York") => 2_789.6,
  pair("Los Angeles", "Sydney") => 7_497,
}

distances[ pair("Los Angeles", "New York") ]    # => 2789.6
distances[ pair("New York", "Los Angeles") ]    # => 2789.6
distances[ pair("Sydney", "Los Angeles") ]      # => 7497
```